# Issue with using a range, for a Stacked Column Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Waterfall chart (xlColumnStacked), with `rngToSelect` as the data to use.  However, I am receiving the ***"method range of object _global failed"*** error when I try to run the Macro.  Can anyone see why I am receiving this error?

I declare the `rngToSelect` at the top, and then call it when I am adding in the Source Data.

```
Sub Waterfall()
'
' Waterfall Macro
'

'
Dim rngData As Range
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim rngToSelect As Range

Set rngData = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

Set rngToSelect = Range(rngData.Cells(1, 1), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, 1))
For intCounter = 1 To rngData.Columns.Count
    If rngData.Cells(1, intCounter).Value <> "Values" Then
        Set rngToSelect = Union(rngToSelect, Range(rngData.Cells(1, intCounter), rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, intCounter)))
    End If
Next intCounter

rngToSelect.Select

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rngToSelect)
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnStacked


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing the following:

**Instead of:** `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rngToSelect)`

I did:

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rngToSelect`